# How does `sshd` perform logging in activity?

Tags: ssh, login

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/489913/674

> connecting using SSH counts as logging in.

From [How can I run a process as its owner or become its owner without logging in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489924/how-can-i-run-a-process-as-its-owner-or-become-its-owner-without-logging-in#comment898717_489962)

> connecting with SSH, doesn’t involve `login`

How does `sshd` perform logging in activity? Is it not done by invoking the `login` program?

Although not showing ssh directly, APUE shows a figure for how `rlogin` works, and also says

> We  show  two  calls  to exec between  the `rlogind` server  and  the  login  shell,
>   because the `login` program is usually between the two to validate the user.

Does `sshd` also `exec` `login` to perform logging in?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram you present is pretty much the same high-level path for `rlogin`, `telnet`, `ssh` and other network-based processes that provide interactive shells to the user.

The daemon accepting the connecting will perform authentication.  Upon success it will allocate a pty for the interactive user session, and create the child (user) session to talk to the pty.  The daemon process then handles the communication between the pty and the network.

At login time the daemon may also perform other housekeeping functions (eg update `lastlogin`, `utmp`, `wtmp`, audit logs, etc etc).  There's a *lot* of background tasks that are performed.

`sshd` can be configured in many different ways; there is a `UseLogin` parameter that can be used to create the user session.  It defaults to 'no'

```
% sudo grep UseLogin /etc/ssh/sshd_config
#UseLogin no
```

Setting this to `yes` is not recomemnded  (e.g. [Uselogin in sshd_config](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207888/uselogin-in-sshd-config) )

Answer (score 1):

APUE is a bit outdated, or it doesn't fit very well with the modern Linux userspace(it's still UNIX, not modern Linux Distro).

On modern Linux Distro, SSH server login you by authenticate you through network and create a session (by talking to session manager). A remote session, as shown in part of your picture, works by login manager forwarding your input data from network socket to pty master, so shell can work through pty slave. Pty is totally another topic.

What your pic really showing is the old system in which there's no session manager at all.  Like Stephen said in another answer, this just forms totally different type of "session".

On modern system, sessions are usually all created by session manager, which offers a much easier structure for administrator user.